# How expand navbar from the topside using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

On the topside i have button "MENU" and below img logo. Now menu expand from the bottom of the button. I want to expand from the topside and when menu is expanded button should be under navigation list not above.

Here the code:

```
    <header>

    <div>
        
        <nav class="navbar bg-lightt navbar-expand-xlg">

            <div class="mx-auto">

                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
                    <span>MENU</span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">

                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

        <div class="logo">
    
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="img/LOGO.png" class="logo" alt="">
            </a>
    
        </div>
        
    </div>


</header>
```

Comment: Your problem is very vague, can you clarify? Images / show a working example, not just raw html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the logo position to absolute and position it before the `<nav>` in the html code, then you could put the menu button `navbar-toggler` after the actual `navbar` like this:

```css
.logo  {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header>
    <div>
        <div class="logo">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b?s=64&d=identicon" class="logo" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar bg-lightt navbar-expand-xlg">
            <div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div class="mx-auto">
                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
                    <span>MENU</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Do you know how remove this "MENU" jump at the end or at the start when menu collapse?

Comment: You would have to look at the function that handles the `data-bs-toggle="collapse"`. It seems that it should change the height fully to 0 before hiding the `data-bs-target`. I don't know at the top of my head, but you could post it as another question.